# Do mobile browsers support 4k video using HTML5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, google-chrome

I have a basic webpage that attempts to load a 4K video in an HTML5 video tag:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/pvxtesting/4ktest/index.html

This works on desktop Chrome browser, but fails to work on mobile Chrome (verified on iPhone 8 and Nexus 9).

We managed to determine a similarly encoded video (same resolution and bit rate) of shorter duration with file size of 2 MB only starts to work on some mobile browsers. But videos of longer duration and larger file sizes, such as the example with 15 MB, fail to load. The network monitor shows buffering happening upto 1.4 MB but then it suddenly stops without the HTML5 video *readyState* being updated. We are generally observing this issue for videos above size 1080p on mobile browsers.

Do mobile browsers have video resolution / bitrate limits for AVC? If so, how do we determine this at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 specification only considers video formats and not file size. For large video files, the browser might or might not load it properly if memory is limited. You can check if a video format is supported via `HTMLVideoElement::canPlayType` but even that does not return guaranteed results since the three possible return values are

- "probably"
- "maybe"
- empty string (definitely not)

For huge videos you might want to consider streaming them via websockets to a `<video>` tag. That should be more reliable and give you more control.